# Kohana : Unable to Display $query on the webpage

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

Started Learning Kohana3.3 & now i'm stuck at displaying the Data from the Database on to my index page.

APPPATH/classes/Controller/Hellp.php :

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No Direct Script Access');

Class Controller_Hello extends Controller_template
{
  public $template = 'site';

  public function action_index()
  {
    $msg1 = "Above Value";
    $this->template->msg ="H W !!!!!" ;
    echo $msg1;

    // Database query
    $query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM users')->execute();
    echo $query[1];    
  }
}
```

APPPATH/View/site.php :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>We've got a message for you!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {font-family: Georgia;}
        h1 {font-style: italic;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
    <?php echo $msg; ?>
    </h1>
    <p>We just wanted to say it! :)</p>
    <?php echo $query; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the Error :

> ErrorException [ Notice ]: Array to string conversion

Please help with two things :

- Resolve the error.
- Display the values of the User table on the index page with minimal code.

Thanks !

Comment: `$query[1]` is a *row*, the second row of your dataset, which is an array. You could try `var_dump($query);` to actually see what is there.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier : That didn't help !! 

What i see on my page is :

C:\wamp64\www\kohana\application\classes\Controller\Hello.php:14:
object(Database_MySQL_Result)[23]
  protected '_internal_row' => int 0
  protected '_query' => string 'SELECT * FROM users' (length=19)
  protected '_result' => resource(80, mysql result)
  protected '_total_rows' => int 5
  protected '_current_row' => int 0
  protected '_as_object' => boolean false
  protected '_object_params' => null

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier : None of them solve my Question .

Comment: No, because your question stems from misunderstanding of echo, arrays and objects. No answer on the internet will solve your problem, you have to start understanding what you are doing, or be damned to be stuck on simple stuff forever. `$query`, according to your own comment, is not an array. Read the documentation from Kohana, learn how to get your result set from the `$query` object, and better yourself.

Comment: RTFM: http://v2docs.kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/results